# compressing a huge set of similar strings

Tags: python, algorithm, compression

I am looking at a python script that maintains a huge set of strings. The strings are actually full paths to log file names from a regression test runs. The number of files is so large that the script starts hitting the virtual address space limit.

The strings like those have little entropy, so I think compressing them would work nicely. The problem is that the compression libraries I considered (like the ones discussed at [Python - Compress Ascii String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12871775/python-compress-ascii-string)) seem to compress each sting individually (storing all the information required for decompression). Common sense suggests that it would be much more efficient space-wise to compress the whole set of strings into a single global blob/dictionary and refer to individual strings using some sort of short references.

Here is some (pseudo) code to clarify the idea:

```
class TestResult:
    def __init__(self):
        self._Id         = None
        ....
        self.__appLogList = []
        return
....
    def setAppLogList(self, currentAppLogList):
        self.__appLogList = currentAppLogList
        # what I want to do here instead is 
        # for each s in currentAppLogList
        # add s to global compressed blob and
        # store reference in __appLogList

    def getAppLogList(self):
        return self.__appLogList
        self.__appLogList = currentAppLogList
        # what I want to do here instead is 
        # currentAppLogList = []
        # for each ref in __appLogList
        # decompress ref into string s and add s to currentAppLogList
        # return currentAppLogList

# for each test
# add new TestResult to result map
# setAppLogList

# for selected tests
# getAppLogList and access logs
```

Is this possible to do using existing publicly available Python libraries?

Comment: You have so many strings that you hit the VM limit?! For a 32-bit machine, that happens at around 1-2GB...how many file names are we talking here?

Comment: Also, `getAppLogList()` would just decompress everything into its return value...wouldn't that have the exact same problem?

Comment: What's the distribution of string lengths?  The expected number of strings?  Are there, e.g., a great many common prefixes, or is the "little entropy" distributed more-or-less uniformly across all index positions?  Do you need to use an in-memory approach, or can you store info on disk?  How many distinct characters appear across all the strings (IOW, what's "the alphabet")?

Comment: Rather than compressing the list, perhaps a tree structure would be more appropriate...

Comment: A problem with compressing the whole set of strings into a single thing is that doing so would likely require having them all in memory at once. To avoid that you would need to write them all to a file and then make two passes through it, one to analyze it, and another to use that information to compress it. You best bet might be an alternative data structure, like the hierarchical tree structure already suggested.

Comment: @nneonneo 100K tests, 100 logs per test, 200 char full path => 2G

Comment: @twalberg a tree (trie-?) may be used under the covers of the algorithm, but I think "compression" is a better high-level name for the problem

Comment: @Tim Peters Something like common_path/unique_path/componentId_date_time.log, but I would rather not rely on this in the algorithm

Comment: Use a [trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie). Each node is a path segment. The leaf nodes are the file names. If each node has a pointer to its parent, then you can easily reconstruct the full path name by walking up the parent chain to the root. The Wikipedia article has a dictionary-based trie implementation in Python.

Comment: @martineau Ah... From your original description it was a bit unclear whether you were talking about something like a tree or prefix/suffix sort of arrangement, which I think would be the right way to go (although selecting the specific data structure and algorithms would require knowing a bit more about the actual data and how you intend to use it), or something like gzip/bzip2/etc. compression...

Comment: Would storing the strings (uncompressed) in a disk-based datebase and then looking them up as needed via some sort of index or offset be feasible?

Comment: The code holds locks while writing/reading the data; I would rather not touch any secondary storage right there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found no ready-to-use implementation that I could apply the problem staying within the time constraints. It appears that none exists at this time. Here are some directions that I considered.

Suffix arrays are the contemporary substitute of the suggested trie trees. Suffix arrays can be used to implement substring search very efficiently. However it is not clear right away how to use them for my problem. Overview of suffix arrays: Puglisi, S. J., Smyth, W. F., & Turpin, A. H. (2007). A taxonomy of suffix array construction algorithms. ACM Computing Surveys (CSUR), 39(2), 4.

This research is directly applicable to my problem: Brisaboa, N. R., Cánovas, R., Claude, F., Martínez-Prieto, M. A., & Navarro, G. (2011). Compressed string dictionaries. In Experimental Algorithms (pp. 136-147). Springer Berlin Heidelberg. Unfortunately, no implementation to download and reuse.

Grammar-based parser: Larsson, N. J., & Moffat, A. (2000). Off-line dictionary-based compression. Proceedings of the IEEE, 88(11), 1722-1732. Implementation is available. All the strings are required to be in memory in order to compute the grammar. I can probably collect first 1000 strings and compute the grammar; alternatively I can do a full run (up until the memory failure), log all strings and compute the grammar. Possible problem: strings evolve over time (names include dates/times). Not optimal compression rate; besides it is not clear what happens if there is a string that does not fit the pre-computed grammar. Maybe such a string won’t be compressed at all. This solution is not as efficient as the previous research, and still requires considerable effort in coding and testing.

Comment: Can you upload a small subset of your urls somewhere. ~ 200 MB would be fine. In my opinion patricia trie would be much more useful. As far as paths are concerned you have common beginnings and paths differ at the ends. I might be able to help you with the solution.

Comment: I have already done something similar with database records modifying the solution for paths must not be very difficult.

Comment: Thanks. I was looking for something like implementation of the idea of Brisaboa at al being in public access for some time and actively used by community. I am not eager to plug in a freshly written code, and will not be able to persuade the rest of my team to do it. I am better off just splitting the test suite into several parts.

Answer (score 3):

This is a variation or extension of my previous answer. The primary difference is that it's able to "compress" the strings potentially much more by taking advantage of the fact that they're actually file paths with possibly one or more common sub-components. This redundancy is eliminated by building a tree data structure from this information meaning that for any given level, each unique component value is only stored once. The tree data structure itself is implemented using what is essentially a dictionary of dictionaries. Its creation ought to be relatively fast due to it use of the built-in `reduce()` function.

The updated version below now has the property that -- unlike with previous one -- what's created can be pickled, which means it can be saved and read back intact later from a file.

Like my other [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19455242/355230), this isn't doing what you call "real" compression, however I think doing something like might be overkill for what you're trying to accomplish since this would solve your problem, is relatively quick, plus would be much simpler to maintain, enhance, and extend later.

```
import collections
import cPickle as pickle  # use C version for performance
import operator
import os

class DefaultDict(collections.defaultdict):
    """  pickle-able defaultdict """
    def __reduce__(self):
        args = (self.default_factory,) if self.default_factory else tuple()
        return type(self), args, None, None, self.iteritems()

def Tree(): return DefaultDict(Tree)
class Leaf(object): pass

def print_tree(d, level=0, indent=' '*4):
    """ Tree structure pretty printer """
    if not d:
        print indent * level + '<empty>'
    else:
        for key, value in sorted(d.iteritems()):
            print indent * level + str(key)
            if isinstance(value, dict):
                print_tree(value, level+1, indent)
            elif not isinstance(value, Leaf):
                print indent * (level+1) + str(value)

# create Tree structure from paths
tree = Tree()
LEAF = Leaf()
with open('log_file_paths.txt') as inf:
    for line in inf:
        path = line.strip().split(os.sep)
        reduce(operator.getitem, path[:-1], tree)[path[-1]] = LEAF
print_tree(tree)

# save tree to a file
with open('file_tree.pk', 'wb') as outf:
    pickle.dump(tree, outf, pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)

# try reading it back in
del tree
with open('file_tree.pk', 'rb') as inf:
    tree = pickle.load(inf)
print_tree(tree)  # display reconstituted tree
```

So if the input file consisted of these file paths:

```
tests/first/set1.log
tests/first/set2.log
tests/first/subfirst/set3.log
tests/first/subfirst/set4.log
tests/second/set5.log
tests/second/subsecond/set6.log
tests/second/subsecond/subsubsecond/set7.log
tests/third/set8.log
```

The following tree structure is what gets created in memory and displayed (and later written, read back, and redisplayed) to hold them:

```
tests
    first
        set1.log
        set2.log
        subfirst
            set3.log
            set4.log
    second
        set5.log
        subsecond
            set6.log
            subsubsecond
                set7.log
    third
        set8.log
```

Comment: poor compression on /1/component1.2013.10.22.15-00-00.log,/1/component2.2013.10.22.15-00-00.log,/2/component1.2013.10.22.15-00-00.log,/2/component2.2013.10.22.15-00-00.log

Answer (score 2):

Here's the simplest thing I can think of that might work. It "compresses" the data by only storing each unique directory path once in a dictionary. All files in any given directory are stored in a `list`. For testing purposes the sample code below just reads an input file composed of one full file path per line.

```
from collections import defaultdict
import os

directories = defaultdict(list)

with open('log_file_paths.txt') as inf:
    for path in (line.strip() for line in inf):
        dir_path, file_name = os.path.split(path)
        directories[dir_path].append(file_name)

for path in directories:
    print path
    for file_name in directories[path]:
        print '   ', file_name
```

Comment: That's the idea. But I wanted to use a "real" compression algorithm that would reuse repeating patterns anywhere in the strings, not just a prefix.

Answer (score 1):

Right now, I only have a java solution in place. You can use it as a standalone script. Please change the value in code [here](https://github.com/anupamsaini/Trie/blob/master/src/com/anupam/java/tries/patricia/PatriciaTrieManager.java#L16) to the path of your file and execute.

You can modify search method according to your need, The project also has an ant script that you can customize if required.

For example if you are searching for the file name:

> sipproxy0-dc0-auto-node-aware-10.20131021_213407_288.snapshot.log

You would have to provide the complete path, for i.e:

> C:\ccview\aglagole_2_cloudute\tserver_ddpsf\siptserver\CloudUte\unittest\worker_log\aglagole\logs\sipproxy0-dc0-auto-node-aware-10.20131021_213407_288.snapshot.log

To  bring down memory usage I would recommend that you generate a hash for the common part in each row (Google's Guava lib has a pretty good implementation)

> C:\ccview\aglagole_2_cloudute\tserver_ddpsf\siptserver\CloudUte\unittest\worker_log\aglagole\logs

Let me know if you face any out of memory issues.

Comment: Just in case I make some changes that makes the code useless :) The last commit at which everything works : **eeb838e17bd2828988c9b5f1a1e69ffd600afd3f**