# compressing individual lines of text separately using common phrases in a global dictionary

Tags: c++, c, encoding, dictionary, compression

Is there any open source library or algorithm available to look at what phrases or words are most common among individual lines of text in a file and create a global dictionary that would then be used to compress the lines of text separately? Preferably the code if available would be in C or C++.

I found this question that I think was similar but did not have an answer that meets what I am looking for:

[compressing a huge set of similar strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19437009/compressing-a-huge-set-of-similar-strings)

Comment: Finding similar strings of bytes and creating dictionaries is most what compression algorithms do. A string is essentially synonymous to a string of bytes, with a `0` at the end. No pun intended, just realised.

Comment: The technique is quite common and it's called "Bag of Words". http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bag-of-words_model

Comment: No, "Bag Of Words" discards the order. That is not what's asked here.

Answer (score 0):

There are three important things to recognize here.

1. The value of replacing a word by a code depends on its frequency and its length. Replacing "a" isn't worth a lot, even if it appears very often.
2. Once you've identified the most common words, phrases can be found by looking for occurrences of two common words appearing side by side. (In most grammars, word repetition is fairly rare.)
3. However, one of the biggest sources of redundancy in text is actually the amount of bits needed to predict the next letter. That's typically about 2, given the preceding text. Do you really need word-based compression when letter-based compression is so much easier?

Comment: in the text I am looking to compress, there will be repeated expressions or sets of words that will occur frequently enough.

Comment: @user102023: What I meant by word repetition is `"Foo Foo Foo"`. Normally in step 2 you look for word pairs "Foo Bar" when both words are individually frequent. BTW there's an implicit step 2B. If you've found that "Foo Bar" is common, you should then look if it occurs  in combination with a third word.

Answer (score 0):

I did some more searching, and I think I have found my answer.

I came across this page discussing improving compression by using boosters

http://mainroach.blogspot.com/2013/08/boosting-text-compression-with-dense.html

That page provided a link to the research paper

http://www.dcc.uchile.cl/~gnavarro/ps/tcj11.pdf

and also to the source code used to do the compression

http://vios.dc.fi.udc.es/codes/download.html

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  [zlib](http://zlib.net/), an open source compression library in C, provides the `deflateSetDictonary()` and `inflateSetDictionary()` routines for this purpose.  You provide up to 32K of seed data in which the compressor will look for matching strings.  The same dictionary needs to reside on both ends.  If you are compressing lots of small pieces of data with a lot of commonality, this can greatly improve compression.  Your "lines of text" certainly qualify as small pieces of data.