# String Compression: Output Alphabet Restricted to Alphanumeric Characters

Tags: python, string, compression

I have a long string and I would like to compress it to a new string with the restriction that the **output** alphabet only contains `[a-z]` `[A-Z]` and `[0-9]` characters.

How can I do this, specifically in Python?

Comment: That's unfortunate. Base62 is much more awkward than base64

Comment: I doubt very much that you can actually figure out a way to *compress* data this way -- You could, however, probably *encode* data this way if that's what you're after...

Comment: I don't think you understand your own question. Are you trying to compress the string, in some (perfectly or at least approximately) reversible way? Or just filter the string to only the alphanumeric characters, irreversibly forgetting everything that got thrown out?

Comment: Meanwhile, is "the case where the input string contains ASCII characters" not actually your case? If so, what's the problem? If not, what non-ASCII characters do you have, what encoding are they in (if this is Python 2), and what do you want to do with them?

Comment: @abarnert. I am seeking lossless (and of course reversible) compression. In this case compression defined by the ratio of number of characters bw the input and output strings.

Comment: Is the limitation to [a-z], [A-Z] and [0-9] characters a hard requirement?  If you just want the output to pass through normal ascii channels, you could compress the data with something standard (e.g. gzip) and then encode with a standard off-the-shelf method (uuencode, base64, etc.) to transportable ascii.

Comment: Thanks @John1024. I am interested in a solution that relaxes the constraint to "output strings that pass through standard ASCII channels" I will relax the constraint if the problem as it stands has no feasible solution.

Comment: I don't understand, the [answer by Sergey](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12871916/5987) in that other thread appears to be exactly what you need.

Comment: I _still_ don't understand why you had a problem with "the case when the input string contains ASCII characters". What are you trying to encode? If it's a `str`/`bytes` in UTF-8 or some other defined encoding, that's fine; you can just ignore the ASCII bit. But if it's a `unicode`/`str`, then it _is_ a problem, and we need to explain how to solve it.

Comment: Thanks abarnert. I have just removed that sentence. I am interested in the case where the input string is ASCII. What I meant to say is that the thread I am referring to discusses a different problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While many encoding algorithms *can* take an arbitrary output range, most implementations can't, and many algorithms are much less efficient if the output range isn't a power of 2/16/256.

So, you want to split this into two parts: First compress one byte stream to another. Then encode the output byte stream into alphanumeric characters. (If you're starting with something that isn't a byte stream, like a Python 3 string or a Python 2 `unicode`, then there's a zeroth step of encoding it into a byte stream.)

For example, if you wanted base64, you could do this:

```
import base64, zlib
compressed_bytes = zlib.compress(plain_bytes)
compressed_text = base64.b64encode(compressed_bytes)
```

---

Unfortunately, you don't want base-64, because that includes a few non-alphanumeric characters.

You can use [base32](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base32), which has just the capital letters and 6 digits, and the only change to your code is `b32encode` instead of `encode`. But that's a bit wasteful, because it's only using 5 out of every 8 bits, when you could in theory use ~5.594 of each 8 bits.

If you want to do this optimally, and you can't bend the requirement for alphanumeric characters only, base62 is very complicated, because you can't do it byte by byte, but only in chunks of 7936 bytes at a time. That's not going to be fun, or efficient. You can get reasonably close to optimal by chunking, say, 32 bytes at a time and wasting the leftover bits. But you might be better off using base64 plus an escaping mechanism to handle the two characters that don't fit into your scheme. For example:

```
def b62encode(plain):
    b64 = base64.b64encode(plain)
    return b64.replace('0', '00').replace('+', '01').replace('/', '02')

def b62decode(data):
     b64 = '0'.join(part.replace('01', '+').replace('02', '/') 
                    for part in data.split('00'))
     return base64.b64decode(b64)
```

For comparison, here's how much each algorithm expands your binary data:

- base32: 60.0%
- fake base62: 39.2%
- realistic base62: ~38%
- optimal base62: 34.4%
- base64: 33%

The point of partial-byte transfer encodings like base64 is that they're dead-simple and run fast. While you *can* extend it to partial-bit encodings like base62, you lose all of the advantages… so if the fake base62 isn't good enough, I'd suggest using something completely different instead.

---

To reverse this, reverse all the same steps in reverse order.

Putting it all together, using the fake base62, and using `unicode`/Python 3 strings:

```
plain_bytes = plain_text.encode('utf-8')
compressed_bytes = zlib.compress(plain_bytes)
b62_bytes = b62encode(compressed_bytes)
b62_text = b62_bytes.decode('ascii')

b62_bytes = b62_text.encode('ascii')
compressed_bytes = b62decode(b62_bytes)
plain_bytes = zlib.decompress(compressed_bytes)
plain_text = plain_bytes.decode('utf-8')
```

And that's about as complicated as it can get.

Comment: Thanks! I get the error encode takes exactly two arguments (1 given)

Comment: @Josh: Sorry, `b64encode` or `encodestring`. The `encode` function is to encode a whole file. I'll edit it. Thanks for the catch.

Comment: Thanks @abarnert Not sure if this is possible with this solution, but is there any way to decode the output and get back the original input? (i.e. reverse the compression)

Comment: @Josh: Sure, I'll add that.

Comment: Whoever edited this at the same time as me to add a `b62decode` function, it looked good at first glance, but then I got an error and couldn't accept it, and now it's not showing up in history. Can you try again?

Comment: @abarnert I added it again. Sorry for interfering your edit, but I thought somebody would like to have the decode-function...

Comment: @koffein: Thanks, and sorry for the hassle. I re-edited it slightly so it doesn't scroll off the right end of the page.

Comment: See my answer for a much simpler and more efficient encoding scheme.

Answer (score 0):

There is a much simpler encoding scheme than base 62 or modifications of base 64 for limiting the output to 62 values.  Take your input as a stream of bits (which in fact it is), and then encode either five or six bits as each output character.  If the five bits are 00000 or 00001, then encode it as your first two characters from your set of 62.  Otherwise, take one more bit, giving you 60 possible values.  Use your remaining 60 characters for those.  Continue with the remaining bits.  Pad with zero bits on the end to get your last five or six bits.

Decoding is even simpler.  You just emit five or six bits for each character received.  You throw away any extra bits at the end that don't make up a full byte.

The expansion resulting from this scheme is 35%, close to the theoretical optimal of 34.36%.